# How many GET_LOCKs can a MySQL handle?

Tags: mysql, limit, limits, locks

How many GET_LOCKS can be handled by a mysql server - by the whole server. I wasn´t able to find anything about its limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per MySQL documentation [GET_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) you cannot hold more than one lock per connection.

As it says

> If you have a lock obtained with GET_LOCK(), it is released when you
>   execute RELEASE_LOCK(), execute a new GET_LOCK(), or your connection
>   terminates (either normally or abnormally).

So essentially, it depends on No.Of connection. I would say the equation would

```
No.of GET_LOCK handled = NO.Of Connections handled
```

I see there is a bug logged where people suggested to have concurrent lock per connection. See here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1118

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I went by the spec; though there is a bug logged for having concurrent lock per connection. Not sure if that's been released and you are talking about that.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I don't think so; I quoted the particular in answer. If you already have one lock; moment you try to acquire another lock on that same connection; holding lock gets released. that's what I understood.

Comment: For future refrences, it's not true anymore for mysql 5.7 or higher.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('s',10);
+------------------+
| GET_LOCK('s',10) |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('t',10);
+------------------+
| GET_LOCK('t',10) |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('b',10);
+------------------+
| GET_LOCK('b',10) |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK('b');
+-------------------+
| IS_FREE_LOCK('b') |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK('t');
+-------------------+
| IS_FREE_LOCK('t') |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK('s');
+-------------------+
| IS_FREE_LOCK('s') |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: wrong example... the question is based on "by server" not "by connection".